# How to change harddrive spindown time?

Tags: hard-drive, spindown, standby

if I run my notebook on battery mode, ubuntu spindown my hardrive every few seconds. How can I fix that? 
I have tried it with `sudo hdparm -S 127 /dev/sda*` but I am not able to disable the spindown and can´t find the reason for this "bug". Running Ubuntu 12.04 - Bug is since 12.04

---

Recent updates are installed, the problem is still recent. I can change the settings via. `sudo hdparm -B 127` but if I change hdparm.conf, Ubuntu does not recognize it.

```
/dev/sda {
  apm_battery=127
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the bug affecting you:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hdparm/+bug/952556

It's supposed to be solved in updates, so please check for updates and apply the latest ones (the one you want is hdparm (9.37-0ubuntu3.1) ). I suggest you reboot after applying them to be on the safe side.

If that doesn't help, the bug has some more suggestions to try. For instance, open a terminal and:

```
sudo gedit /etc/hdparm.conf
```

At the very end add this (on a new line):

```
apm_battery = 128
```

Then save the file.

You can try this manually by running

```
sudo hdparm -B 128 /dev/sda
```

but this will not persist once you've rebooted, so if it works for you, add it to the file as explained above.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is/was caused the `laptop_mode-tools`. `laptop_mode-tools` ignores your `/etc/hdparm.conf` settings. To fix it, edit `sudo gedit /etc/laptop-mode`. Find this part:

```
#
# Power management for HD (hdparm -B values)
#
BATT_HD_POWERMGMT=1
```

And change it to:

```
 #
 # Power management for HD (hdparm -B values)
 #
 BATT_HD_POWERMGMT=127
```

To check if your new config is in use, disconnect from Power-Supply run:

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda
```