# Laptop-mode-tools and hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, asus, hdparm, spindown

I use laptop-mode-tools to save battery on my [Asus TUF A17](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/asus-a17-tuf766iu). I works fine but not for the hard disk : this one is going too much to sleep and wake up after every 10 seconds. So the `Load_Cycle_Count` is increasing too much.

```
meloli@Asus-A17:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep Load_Cycle_Count
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       4321
```

I tried `sudo hdparm -B 255 /dev/sda` or `sudo hdparm -B 254 /dev/sda` wbut it does nothing...

The only things who seems to work is using `spindown time`

```
meloli@Asus-A17:~$ sudo hdparm -B 254 /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level      = 254
meloli@Asus-A17:~$ sudo hdparm -S 242 /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 setting standby to 242 (1 hours)
```

I tried something like this in `/etc/hdparm.conf` but I does nothin when using battery.

```
/dev/sda {
#   apm = 127
   apm_battery = 254
   spindown_time = 241
}
 
command_line {
    hdparm -S 241 /dev/sda
}
```

Everything works fine when using AC.

How to get my hard disk not to go to sleep too quickly when using laptop-mode-tools ?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this because I have no idea how long you want your drives to spin for when on battery power. However, using a `-B` value greater than 128 will tell the drive "never spin down" so it doesn't matter what you set with `-S` as the APM value takes precedence over spin down. [The answer over here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1311596/1091774) might point you in the right direction for a solution.

Comment: I found the parameter `BATT_HD_POWERMGMT=1` in `/etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf` which overrides /etc/hdparm.conf. I will try to change this. Source :  https://askubuntu.com/questions/137544/how-to-change-harddrive-spindown-time